# how to disable link on "Created By" column vale of a list item in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In a sharepoint list, there is a column name "Created By" and "Modified By". When we click on this column values, the page is redirected to user info page. I want to disable this redirection. I just want to show the user who created or modified. how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `List - > Settings -> List Settings`

Under "**Columns**"

Click "Created by" to open column settings

Under "**Additional Column Settings**"
Change Show Filed  to "**Name**".

Repeat the above steps for '**Modified by**"

This will just Show the Name and will not have the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075418/access-sharepoint-group-item-columns..Can you give me a suggestion on this?

Comment: I have added a comment in your other question. please check.